# Unable to read YAML with jinja2 variables in it with ruamel

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am trying to parse a file from the helm bundle which contains lots of jinja variables in it. When I try to read the file using ruamel.yaml python library it throws following exception:

```
----- Python Traceback -----
File "/Users/bhupesh.gupta/Projects/node-python-poc/yaml-read-file-script.py", line 16, in <module>
  data = list(yaml.load_all(input))
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 451, in load_all
  for d in self.load_all(fp):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 461, in load_all
  yield constructor.get_data()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 115, in get_data
  return self.construct_document(self.composer.get_node())
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 66, in get_node
  return self.compose_document()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 99, in compose_document
  node = self.compose_node(None, None)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 143, in compose_node
  node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 223, in compose_mapping_node
  item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 143, in compose_node
  node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 223, in compose_mapping_node
  item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 143, in compose_node
  node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 216, in compose_mapping_node
  while not self.parser.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/parser.py", line 146, in check_event
  self.current_event = self.state()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/parser.py", line 597, in parse_block_mapping_key
  if self.scanner.check_token(KeyToken):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/scanner.py", line 1794, in check_token
  while self.need_more_tokens():
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/scanner.py", line 211, in need_more_tokens
  self.stale_possible_simple_keys()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/scanner.py", line 360, in stale_possible_simple_keys
  raise ScannerError(
ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
in "<unicode string>", line 20, column 1:
  <<{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
  ^ (line: 20)
could not find expected ':'
in "<unicode string>", line 21, column 2:
   #<{- end }}
```

Following is the file which I am trying to parse:

```
{{- $profileFilePath := printf "%s/%s%s" "dep_configs" .Values.global.networkFunction.profile ".yaml" -}}
{{- $isFileAvail := .Files.Glob $profileFilePath }}
{{- $nameprefixStr :=  . }}
{{- if $isFileAvail }}
{{- $profileValues := $.Files.Get $profileFilePath | fromYaml }}
{{- if not (empty .Values.global.k8sPlatform.namePrefix) }}
{{- $nameprefixStr =  printf "%s-enodeb-%s-%s-%s" (lower $.Values.global.k8sPlatform.namePrefix) (lower $.Values.global.env.VRAN_ENB_ID)  (lower $profileValues.networkFunction.nfType) (lower $.Values.global.env.VRAN_NF_ID) -}}
{{- else }}
{{- $nameprefixStr =  printf "enodeb-%s-%s-%s" (lower $.Values.global.env.VRAN_ENB_ID)  (lower $profileValues.networkFunction.nfType) (lower $.Values.global.env.VRAN_NF_ID) -}}
{{- end }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-pod
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-pod
{{- with $.Values.global.k8sPlatform.labels }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
  annotations:
    {{- /* ##### fill the annotation for K8S looping through nw list */}}
    {{- $k8slistString := "" }}
    {{- $releaseName := $.Release.Name }}
    {{- range $.Values.cnfNetworks.cnfcNwList }}
       {{- if or ( eq .cniPluginType "sriov")  (eq .cniPluginType "sriov-dpdk") }}
         {{- if not (empty $k8slistString) }}
          {{- $k8slistString = printf "%s," $k8slistString }}
         {{- end }}
         {{- $intfAnnotation := printf "%s-%s@%s" $releaseName .cnfcNwType .cnfcNwType }}
         {{- $k8slistString = printf "%s%s" $k8slistString $intfAnnotation }}
       {{- end }}
     {{- end }}
     {{- if not (empty $k8slistString) }}
     k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: {{ $k8slistString }}
     {{- end }}
     {{- /* ##### START fill the annotation for ROBIN case looping through nw list */}}
     {{- $robinvarlistglobal := list  }}
     {{- $varlisttemp := list  }}
     {{- $dictvar := dict }}
     {{- range $.Values.cnfNetworks.cnfcNwList }}
        {{- if eq .cniPluginType "robin" }}
         {{- if not (eq .cnfcNwType "fec") }}

            {{- if (ne .ippool "") }}

            {{- $dictlocal := dict "interface_name" .cnfcNwType "ippool" .ippool }}
            {{- if not (empty .ipam) }}
              {{- if not (empty .ipam.ip) }}
              {{- $_ := set $dictlocal "static_ips" .ipam.ip }}
              {{- end }}
              {{- if not (empty .ipam.mtu) }}
              {{- $_ := set $dictlocal "mtu" .ipam.mtu }}
              {{- end }}
            {{- end }}
            {{- $robinvarlistglobal = append $varlisttemp $dictlocal }}
            {{- $varlisttemp = $robinvarlistglobal }}
            {{- end }}
         {{- else }}
         {{- /* ##### ROBIN FEC case - fill the devices string */}}
         {{- $devicestr := .devicePool }}
     robin.io/devices: '{{- $devicestr}}'
         {{- end }}
       {{- end }}
     {{- end }}
     {{- /* ##### END fill the annotation for ROBIN case looping through nw list */}}

     {{- if not (empty $robinvarlistglobal) }}
     robin.io/networks: '{{- $robinvarlistglobal | toJson}}'
     {{- end }}
     {{- if not (empty $.Values.global.k8sPlatform.nodeSelector) }}
     {{- if not (empty $.Values.global.k8sPlatform.nodeSelector.rpoolName) }}
     robin.io/robinrpool: {{ $.Values.global.k8sPlatform.nodeSelector.rpoolName }}
     {{- end }}
     {{- end }}
     {{- range $.Values.global.cnfCorrelationInput }}
     cnfcName: {{ .cnfcName }}
     cnfCorrelationIds: {{ .cnfcCorrelationIds | toJson | quote }}
     {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- /* ##### Check if AR ,FEC is enabled ############# */}}
  {{- $ar := 0 }}
  {{- $fec := 0 }}
  {{- $sriov := 0 }}
  {{- $sriovResourceMap := dict }}
  {{- range $.Values.cnfNetworks.cnfcNwList }}
    {{- if and (eq .cnfcNwType "ar") (eq .cniPluginType "sriov") }}
      {{- $ar = (add1 $ar) }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if and (eq .cnfcNwType "fec") (eq .cniPluginType "sriov") }}
      {{- $fec = (add1 $fec) }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (eq .cnfcNwType "sriov") }}
      {{- $sriov = (add1 $sriov) }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- /* ### Loop cnfclist for counting SRIOV interface based on resource nameto get resourcemap### */}}
  {{- range $.Values.cnfNetworks.cnfcNwList }}
     {{- if or (eq .cniPluginType "sriov") (eq .cniPluginType "sriov-dpdk") (eq .cniPluginType "sriov-fec") }}
          {{- if hasKey $sriovResourceMap .resourceName }}
              {{- $_ := set $sriovResourceMap .resourceName (add1 (get $sriovResourceMap .resourceName)) }}
          {{- /* ### End of hasKey ### */}}
          {{- else }}
              {{- $_ := set $sriovResourceMap .resourceName 1 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- /* ### End of hasKey ### */}}
      {{- end }}
      {{- /* ### End of cnfclist for couting SRIOV interface ### */}}
  {{- end }}
  containers:
  - name: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.containername }}
    image: {{ $.Values.global.image.repository }}/{{ $profileValues.image.imageName }}:{{ $profileValues.image.imageTag }}
    imagePullPolicy: {{ $profileValues.image.pullPolicy }}
    {{- /* ### introduce a sleep of 10 for initializing vpp before starting app -NEEDED FOR ROBIN ### */}}
    command: ["bash", "-c", "/opt/ani/helm/entrypoint.sh"]
    #command: ["bash","-c","while true; do sleep 1000; done"]
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-configmap-env
    env:
    - name: NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: MY_POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    - name: MY_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: MY_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: MY_POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    - name: MY_CPU_REQUEST
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: {{ .containerName }}
          resource: requests.cpu
    - name: MY_CPU_LIMIT
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: {{ .containerName }}
          resource: limits.cpu
    - name: MY_MEM_REQUEST
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: {{ .containerName }}
          resource: requests.memory
    - name: MY_MEM_LIMIT
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: {{ .containerName }}
          resource: limits.memory
    volumeMounts:
    #
    # Volumes (common for CU & DU) = entrypoint , memfs, dskfs, provconfig ,hugepages , inject files
    #  CU specific  - mainconfig
    #  DU specific - devices, ar specific
    #
    - mountPath: /opt/ani/helm/entrypoint.sh
      subPath: entrypoint
      name: entrypoint
    - mountPath: /opt/ani/helm/inject-files.sh
      subPath: inject-files
      name: entrypoint
    - mountPath: /memfs
      name: memfs
    - mountPath: /dskfs/
      name: dskfs-fm
    - mountPath: /prov-config
      name: prov-config
    - mountPath: /ipaddr-config
      name: ipaddr-config
    {{- if $.Values.global.networkFunction.main_config }}
    - mountPath: /main-config
      name: main-config
    {{- end }}
    - mountPath: /mnt/huge
      name: hugepage
      readOnly: false
    - name: devices
      mountPath: /sys/devices
      readOnly: false
    {{- if (eq $ar 1) }}
    - mountPath: /dev/kni
      name: kni
    {{- end }}
    {{- if not (empty $.Values.host_volumes) }}
    {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.large }}
    {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.large.hostpath }}
    - mountPath: /inject-files-large
      name: inject-files-large
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.small }}
    {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.small.files }}
    - mountPath: /inject-files-small
      name: inject-files-small
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }} # end inject_files
    resources:
      requests:
        {{- toYaml $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.resources.requests | nindent 8 }}
        {{- range $sriovResourceName,$sriovResourceCount := $sriovResourceMap }}
              {{- printf "%s: %d" $sriovResourceName $sriovResourceCount | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
      limits:
        {{- toYaml $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.resources.limits | nindent 8 }}
        {{- range $sriovResourceName,$sriovResourceCount := $sriovResourceMap }}
              {{- printf "%s: %d" $sriovResourceName $sriovResourceCount | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
    securityContext:
      {{- toYaml $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.securityContext | nindent 6 }}
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - /opt/ani/scripts/{{ $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.liveness.script }}
      initialDelaySeconds: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.liveness.initialDelaySeconds }}
      periodSeconds: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.liveness.periodSeconds }}
      failureThreshold: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.liveness.failureThreshold }}
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: [/bin/sh,-c,/opt/ani/scripts/prestop_exec.sh]
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.runtime.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
  volumes:
  - name: memfs
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
      sizeLimit: {{ $profileValues.networkFunction.config.host_volumes.memfs_storage }}
  - name: dskfs-fm
    # Writes by application on a limited partition
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-pvc-dskfs
  - name: prov-config
    configMap:
      name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-configmap-provini
      items:
      - key: prov.ini
        path: prov.ini
  - name: ipaddr-config
    configMap:
      name: enodeb-{{ $.Values.global.env.VRAN_ENB_ID }}-{{ lower $profileValues.networkFunction.nfType }}-{{ $.Values.global.env.VRAN_NF_ID }}-configmap-ipaddr
      items:
      - key: ipaddr.ini
        path: ip_addr.ini
  - name: entrypoint
    configMap:
      name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-configmap-entrypoint
      defaultMode: 0777
  {{- if $.Values.global.networkFunction.main_config }}
  - name: main-config
    configMap:
      name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-configmap-mainconfig
      items:
      - key: mainconfig
        path: config.xml
      - key: license
        path: license.xml
  {{- end }}
  - name: hugepage
    emptyDir:
      medium: HugePages
  - name: devices
    # Required by dpdk
    hostPath:
      path: /sys/devices
  {{- if (eq $ar 1) }}
  - name: kni
    # Required by kni
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/kni
      type: CharDevice
  {{- end }}
  {{- if not ( empty $.Values.host_volumes) }}
  {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.large }}
  {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.large.hostpath }}
  - name: inject-files-large
    # Used for file-injection. Lab Feature for single node clusters
    hostPath:
      path: {{ $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.large.hostpath }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.small }}
  - name: inject-files-small
    configMap:
      name: {{ $nameprefixStr }}-configmap-inject-small-files
      items:
      {{- range $index, $file:= $.Values.host_volumes.inject_files.small.files }}
        - key: {{ $file.source }}
          path: {{ $file.source }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }} # inject_files.small
  {{- end }} # inject_files
  {{- if not ( empty $.Values.global.env.SECGW_INTERNAL_DNS) }}
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - {{ $.Values.global.env.SECGW_INTERNAL_DNS }}
  {{- end }}
{{- else }}
{{- fail "Deployment file does not exist" }}
{{- end }}
```

It contains 2 YAML documents within single file. Even if I remove the first one it still cannot parse (just for testing) although I need to complete file to be parsed.

Comment: Do you have any documenation on the `{{- with ...`  and `{{- end }}` construct? I can only find [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#with-statement) which seems different to me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here, partly due to limitations in `ruamel.yaml.jinja2`.

The error you indicate is created by the `{{ ... }}` pattern, that occurs on a line of its own, in what seems to be
a jinja2 construct starting with `{{- with` (which correctly gets commented out before loading).

I have not been able to find documentation for that. The [with statement](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#with-statement) in jinja2 is
different, and without proper documentation I hesitate to update the ruamel.yaml.jinja2 extension.
It also doesn't 100% match the `{{ with ....}}` / `{{ end }}` of the go-templates (no dash after the curly braces.

You should pre-process the data to get the offending line out of the way, by
commenting out all the lines between `with` and `end` (the latter at the same indentation level),
but it would nice if this were documented, to give more confidence that is the right approach in general.

```py
import sys
import io
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.split import split
from pathlib import Path

input_file = Path('input.jinja2')
output_file = Path('output.jinja2')

# wty = ('{{ toYaml', '#{{ toYaml')

def reverse(s):
    return s.replace(wty[1], wty[0])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='jinja2')
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.width = 256
yaml.explicit_start = True

def comment_out_with(doc, entry):
    res = []
    end = None
    for line in doc.splitlines(True):
        if end:
            res.append('#<<<' + line)
            if line.startswith(end):
                end = None
            continue
        if line.rstrip().startswith(entry[0]):
            res.append('#<<<' + line)
            end = line.split(entry[0])[0] + entry[1]  # prepend the indentation
            continue
        res.append(line)
    return ''.join(res)

def reverse(s):
    s = s.replace('#<<<{{', '{{')
    s = s.replace('#<{', '{{')
    return s

# list of tuples (data, doc), if data is None, write doc as None cannot have comments
documents = []

for doc, line_nr in split(input_file):
    dd = doc.decode('utf-8')
    for with_entry in [('{{- with', '{{- end'), ('{{ with', '{{ end')]:
        if with_entry[0] in dd:
            dd = comment_out_with(dd, with_entry)
    data = yaml.load(dd)  # jinja2 cannot handle bytes yet
    documents.append((data, doc))

for data, doc in documents:
    if data is None:
        continue
    # make your changes to the YAML data here
    data['spec']['containers'][0]['env'][0]['name'] = 'my_node_name'

with output_file.open('w') as fpo:
    for data, doc in documents:
        if data is None:
            fpo.write(doc.decode('utf-8'))
        else:
            buf = io.StringIO()
            yaml.dump(data, buf)
            fpo.write(reverse(buf.getvalue()))
```

The "trick" with writing the original document is necessary because `ruamel.yaml` cannot
attach comments to `None` (as it cannot be subclassed in a meaningful way).

A minor thing, that is probably not a issue is that most block style sequences have
indentation of 2 with no offset, but the sequences that are the values for the keys `items` and `nameservers`
close to the end of the file have an indentation of 4 with an offset of 2.

Flow style sequences ( `[/bin/sh,-c,/opt/ani/scripts/prestop_exec.sh]` ) get space after the comma.

Apart from these minor "standardisations" that should not affect loading of the converted template ,
the output file differs only in the programmatically updated "my_node_name"

Comment: Hi Anthon, I dug more into it and I found that it's not Jinja but go templating which is very similar to jinja and hence the confusion. The {{- with syntax is from go templating not from jinja. So I think there is nothing much that can be done here. But appreciated your help here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I created a solution for the first document containing nothing but templates. But I cannot find any reference to `{{- with` in the go-template documentation.  So I comment everything out between with and end and then you can roundtrip this with changes.

Comment: it's surely go templating engine, the purpose of `-` within curly braces is to manage whitespaces. Please check out this link which contains the explanation https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/
Also, you can check the official documentation of GO templating engine for whitespace management which tells it clearly. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks I completely missed that, I think I searched the official Go templating pages for `{{- with`, where I probably should have searched just for `{{-`.

Comment: Did we do anything for the above syntax for GO templating??